# Folder permission Issue installing Cocotron

Tags: xcode, macos

I am new, so please forgive. I am installing cocotron and ran into an issue while running install.sh. I receive an error stating I do not have writable access to the folder (libraries\Application Support\Developer\Shared\Xcode\Specifications). I'm logged in as admin, it shows I have R/W access - so not sure what's going on.

The folder library\...\Specifications didn't exist - I thought maybe this was the issue so I created the folder - still same issue.

2015 MBP with OS X 10.11

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had to create the dir path and set permissions in terminal - then it worked.